# Alternative definition of Euclidean operator norm

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

Given $A\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, $\|.\|$ the Euclidean operator norm, and $\rho(A)$ the spectral radius of A, how to show that

$$ \|A\| = \sup\{\rho(AB):B\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}, \|B\|=1\} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: For "$\ge$", use that $\rho(A) \le \|A\|$.

For "$\le$", use that $\rho(XY) = \rho(YX)$, and then use the SVD to find a unitary $B$ such that $\rho(AB) = \|A\|$.

Comment: Thanks! For the second part, select $B$ so $AB$ is normal, then $\rho(AB)=\|AB\|=\|A\|$ if $B$ is unitary. SVD of A is $A=U\Sigma V^H$, then simply picking $B=VU^H$ will do the trick. I don't see any need to use $\rho(XY)=\rho(YX)$??

Comment: I was going to use that $\|\Sigma\| = \rho(\Sigma)$.  But your method works just as well.